# Android Dialog problem with TabView

Tags: android, uitableview, dialog

```
   My problem is when a dialog is opened, if I change the tab,  that dialog is displayed in the activity in the next tab.How to remove that .
```

Pls help.
This occurs because according to my requirement I can interact with the dialog and the view behind at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by dismissing the dialog in onPause() method

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the dialog is open or not on the click of another tab, if open close it.

Comment: I resolved by dismissing the dialog in onPause() method of the activity. When I click on a tab it is showing another acivity. And I cannot access the dialog variable in that activity...

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question

Answer (score 0):

You have a tabhost and a framelayout... just identify the tab changed via calling OnTabChangedListener and perform frameLayout.removeAllView(); and then render a dialog again.. I think it may help...!! if not then can u please describe ur problem in brief...